# Display secondary underlying image on a Imagelist?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a Image list assigned to a listview to display transparent images.

There is a slight issue with this regarding some transparent images that are added, and that is they are sometimes hard to see/find in the listview.

See this example image:

[image]

You will notice that the images (noticeably the mouse) is barely viewable, infact if a empty image was added you would not even see it, the number captions come to the rescue here to show there is something actually there.

But I would like to make the images visually easier to see. I thought maybe having another image underneath the transparent images would work - of course though it could not affect the actual image.

So with that in mind, I made a bitmap of a chessboard grid:

[image]

I feel this would be the most suitable way of representing transparent areas of the images just like Paint.NET etc does.

To further illustrate this example I have modified the original image to show how it would look, if we had the chessboard bitmap as the underlay image:

[image]

Having the chessboard there would indicate there is a list item there in the first place, and the bitmap of the chessboard grid could be darker or an altogether different kind of image. As I said earlier if there was no image you would see nothing at all, so better to show an empty chess grid or other bitmap than nothing.

So, how can I display a second image underneath the original images using a imagelist to give a result similar to the example above? The underneath image could be anything - just another loaded bitmap for example.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not understanding the question, why don't you load the chessboard to a bitmap and then draw your transparent image on it, then you can draw the bitmap anywhere you want?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz but if I did that wouldn't the two images becomes one? Example if I drew the Lion on the chessboard then saved it wouldn't the chessboard save with the Lion? I just want to display the chessboard bitmap underneath - not combine it with the actual images.

Comment: Save what? The image in the imagelist? You already have it in the imagelist. I think I still don't understand the question..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I will be needing to save the images from the imagelist to file, so I don't want the chessboard saving with it. The chessboard bitmap is purely for visually representing the images better in the listview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you store the chessboard as the first image (with index 0) and *make* the overlay image from the current image in the [`OnGetImageIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView.OnGetImageIndex) event handler, it will do what you want to. However I'm not sure how efficient is to *make* the overlay image every time the event is fired.

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1GetImageIndex(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  // make the overlay (with overlay index 1) from the 
  // image with index Item.Index + 1
  ImageList1.Overlay(Item.Index + 1, 1);
  // use the first image from the list as a background
  Item.ImageIndex := 0;
  // and assign just created overlay index for overlay
  Item.OverlayIndex := 1;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and see how well it works. Even if it works I will leave unanswered for a few days and then we can see if there is another approach to it :)

Comment: Sure, I'm also wondering if there's something efficient for this. This looks to me somehow natural, but I don't like to create the mask in the frequently fired event.

Comment: I have tested this on a imagelist with about 200 images and it seems to do the job well enough, I see not negative impacts with it.

Answer (score 1):

I seems that what you need is a TImageList with extra capabilities.

As a starting point, I suggests you to consider **[TImageListEx](http://flylib.com/books/en/1.228.1.173/1/)** described in the book **Inside Delphi 2006**

Excerpt:

> The TImageListEx component is a TImageList descendant that can use the
>   images from another image list to generate disabled images, which can
>   be used on toolbars and other user interface elements.
>
> The TImageListEx component is a TImageList descendant that can use the
>   images from another image list to generate disabled images, which can
>   be used on toolbars and other user interface elements.
>
> There are several benefits of the TImageListEx component:
>
> - It eliminates the need for creating disabled glyphs.
> - It eliminates the need for adding the disabled glyphs to an additional TImageList component at design time.
> - It can drastically reduce the size of the .dfm file and of the entire application, especially in large applications that use a lot of
>     glyphs.
> - It's extremely fast, taking only milliseconds to disable all images in an image list, even when there are number of images.
> - It's extremely lightweight. (If you add it to an application that already uses the standard TImageList component, it won't increase the
>     size of the executable at all, and if you add it to an application
>     that doesn't use the standard TImageList component, the overhead is
>     only 2 KB.)

It's far from your requirements but yet detailed enough to show how to extend TImageList.

Comment: I know about GR32 - I am not sure that would help here though as it involves adjusting a listview/imagelist.

Comment: Sorry, my first attempt to answer is beside the point. Made an edit to suggest something else more valuable. Thanks.